# Why exactly is eval evil?

Tags: clojure, scheme, lisp, common-lisp, eval

I know that Lisp and Scheme programmers usually say that `eval` should be avoided unless strictly necessary. I’ve seen the same recommendation for several programming languages, but I’ve not yet seen a list of clear arguments against the use of `eval`. Where can I find an account of the potential problems of using `eval`?

For example, I know the problems of `GOTO` in procedural programming (makes programs unreadable and hard to maintain, makes security problems hard to find, etc), but I’ve never seen the arguments against `eval`.

Interestingly, the same arguments against `GOTO` should be valid against continuations, but I see that Schemers, for example, won’t say that continuations are "evil" -- you should just be careful when using them. They’re much more likely to frown upon code using `eval` than upon code using continuations (as far as I can see -- I could be wrong).

Comment: eval is not evil, but evil is what eval does

Comment: @yar - I think your comment indicates a very single-dispatch-object-centric world view. It's probably valid for most languages, but would be different in Common Lisp, where methods don't belong to classes and even more different in Clojure, where classes are only supported through Java interop functions. Jay tagged this question as Scheme, which doesn't have any built-in notion of classes or methods (various forms of OO are available as libraries).

Comment: @Zak, you're correct, I only know the languages I know, but even if you're working with a Word document without using Styles you're not being DRY. My point was to use the technology to not repeat yourself. OO is not universal, true...

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the clojure tag to this question, since I believe Clojure users might benefit from exposure to the excellent answers posted here.

Comment: ...well, for Clojure, at least one additional reason applies: You lose compatibility with ClojureScript and its derivatives.

Comment: `goto` is "evil" because it is a form of mutation: effectively, a new value is abruptly assigned to the instruction pointer. Continuations do not involve mutation; a purely functional language can feature continuations. They are more pure than control constructs like *if* and *while*, which were all right by Dijkstra in spite of being a light syntactic sugar over goto and labels.

Answer (score 154):

There are several reasons why one should not use `EVAL`.

**The main reason for beginners is: you don't need it.**

Example (assuming Common Lisp):

EVALuate an expression with different operators:

```lisp
(let ((ops '(+ *)))
  (dolist (op ops)
    (print (eval (list op 1 2 3)))))
```

That's better written as:

```lisp
(let ((ops '(+ *)))
  (dolist (op ops)
    (print (funcall op 1 2 3))))
```

There are lots of examples where beginners learning Lisp think they need `EVAL`, but they don't need it - since expressions are evaluated and one can also evaluate the function part. Most of the time the use of `EVAL` shows a lack of understanding of the evaluator.

It is the same problem with macros. Often beginners write macros, where they should write functions - not understanding what macros are really for and not understanding that a function already does the job.

It often is the wrong tool for the job to use `EVAL` and it often indicates that the beginner does not understand the usual Lisp evaluation rules.

If you think you need `EVAL`, then check if something like `FUNCALL`, `REDUCE` or `APPLY` could be used instead.

- `FUNCALL` - call a function with arguments: `(funcall '+ 1 2 3)`
- `REDUCE` - call a function on a list of values and combine the results: `(reduce '+ '(1 2 3))`
- `APPLY` - call a function with a list as the arguments: `(apply '+ '(1 2 3))`.

Q: do I really need eval or does the compiler/evaluator already what I really want?

**The main reasons to avoid `EVAL` for slightly more advanced users:**

- you want to make sure that your code is compiled, because the compiler can check code for many problems and generates faster code, sometimes MUCH MUCH MUCH (that's factor 1000 ;-) )faster code
- code that's constructed and needs to be evaluated can't be compiled as early as possible.
- eval of arbitrary user input opens up security problems
- some use of evaluation with `EVAL` can happen at the wrong time and create build problems

To explain the last point with a simplified example:

```lisp
(defmacro foo (a b)
  (list (if (eql a 3) 'sin 'cos) b))
```

So, I may want to write a macro that based on the first parameter uses either `SIN` or `COS`.

`(foo 3 4)` does `(sin 4)` and `(foo 1 4)` does `(cos 4)`.

Now we may have:

```
(foo (+ 2 1) 4)
```

This does not give the desired result.

One then may want to repair the macro `FOO` by EVALuating the variable:

```lisp
(defmacro foo (a b)
  (list (if (eql (eval a) 3) 'sin 'cos) b))

(foo (+ 2 1) 4)
```

But then this still does not work:

```
(defun bar (a b)
  (foo a b))
```

The value of the variable is just not known at compile time.

**A general important reason to avoid `EVAL`:** it is often used for ugly hacks.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't understand the last point (evaluation at the wrong time?) -- coud  you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: +1 as this is the real answer - people fall back on `eval` simply because they don't know there's a specific language or library feature to do what they want to do. Similar example from JS: I want to get a property from an object using a dynamic name, so I write: `eval("obj.+" + propName)` when I could have written `obj[propName]`.

Comment: I see what you mean now, Rainer! Thansk!

Comment: @Daniel: `"obj.+"`? Last I checked, `+` isn't valid when using dot-references in JS.

Comment: @Daniel probably meant eval("obj." + propName) which should work as expected.

Comment: +1, I agree with @Daniel that this is the real problem.  I work on a 20 year old Lisp application and I've seen very experienced Lisp programmers use `eval` when it's unnecessary (and more complicated) than doing it correctly.

Comment: Just a comment to remind you that eval is extremely useful in AI applications where the program is the data.

Comment: Hey, who're you calling an ugly hack!?

Comment: When TO use eval: The user needs to entering code in an interactive application. The workaround with builtin libraries is unusually obscure/verbose. When TO use macros: Performance (domain-specific compilation) once bottlenecks are identified, 3rd party library wrapper code generation. These are rare, maybe a total of <5% of the times it's used.

Comment: @KevinKostlan: I would be VERY VERY VERY careful about using EVAL in interactive applications: it creates a HUGE security problem when the user can execute arbitrary code by using EVAL. Especially in a situation when the interactive app runs on your side and the user is someone else somewhere...

Comment: @Rainer Joswig: Yes if you have the server run client commands it better be VERY well sandboxed, which means do NOT "roll your own" malicious code checker. If it's client code running on the client is it a severe threat as long as the client knows that any code ran gets all the privileges of the application?

Comment: @KevinKostlan: depends on the client app. Sometimes I would not want an 'end user' to peek and poke into the platform, or let other programs/services trying to exploit such 'feature', which could be a security problem. Basically injected code could do a lot of interesting things like looking onto the disk and sending the findings to some other place...

Answer (score 44):

`eval` (in any language) is not evil in the same way that a chainsaw is not evil.  It is a tool.  It happens to be a powerful tool that, when misused, can sever limbs and eviscerate (metaphorically speaking), but the same can be said for many tools in a programmer's toolbox including:

- `goto` and friends
- lock-based threading
- continuations
- macros (hygenic or other)
- pointers
- restartable exceptions
- self-modifying code
- ...and a cast of thousands.

If you find yourself having to use any of these powerful, potentially dangerous tools ask yourself three times "why?" in a chain.  For example:

> "Why do I have to use `eval`?" 
>   "Because of foo."  "Why is foo
>   necessary?"  "Because ..."

If you get to the end of that chain and the tool still looks like it's the right thing to do, then do it.  Document the Hell out of it.  Test the Hell out of it.  Double-check correctness and security over and over and over again.  But do it.

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I heard of eval before ("ask yourself why"), but I had never yet heard or read what the potential problems are. I see now from the answers here what they are (security and performance problems).

Comment: And code readability.  Eval can totally screw the flow of code and render it incomprehensible.

Comment: I don't understand why "lock-based threading" [sic] is in your list.  There are forms of concurrency that don't involve locks, and problems with locks are generally well known, but I've never heard anyone describe using locks as "evil".

Comment: asveikau: Lock-based threading is notoriously difficult to get right (I'd guess that 99.44% of production code using locks is bad).  It doesn't compose.  It is prone to turning your "multi-threaded" code into serial code. (Correcting for this just renders the code slow and bloated instead.)  There are good alternatives to lock-based threading, like STM or actor models, that makes the use of it in anything but the lowest-level code evil.

Comment: the "why chain" :) be sure to stop after 3 steps it can hurt.

Comment: Probably worth adding on things like multiple inheritance, and meta-object-protocol since we're in a CL question.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the other evil things, that you should never use :-)

Answer (score 28):

Eval is fine, as long as you know **EXACTLY** what is going into it. Any user input going into it MUST be checked and validated and everything. If you don't know how to be 100% sure, then don't do it.

Basically, a user can type in any code for the language in question, and it will execute. You can imagine for yourself how much damage he can do.

Comment: So if I'm actually *generating* S-expressions based on user input using an algorithm that won't directly copy user input, and if that's easier and clearer in some specific situation than using macros or other techniques, then I suppose there's nothing "evil" about it?     In other words, the only problems with eval are the same with SQL queries and other techniques that use user input directly?

Comment: The reason it's called "evil" is because doing it wrong is so much worse than doing other things wrong. And as we know, newbies will do stuff wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say that code must be validated before evaling it in all circumstances. When implementing a simple REPL for example, you would probably just feed the input into eval unchecked and that wouldn't be a problem (of course when writing a web-based REPL you'd need a sandbox, but that's not the case for normal CLI-REPLs that run on the user's system).

Comment: Like I said, you have to know exactly what happens when you feed what you feed into the eval. If that means "it will execute some commands within the limits of the sandbox", then that's what it means. ;)

Comment: @TorValamo ever heard of jail break?

Answer (score 23):

"When should I use `eval`?" might be a better question.

The short answer is "when your program is intended to write another program at runtime, and then run it". [Genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) is an example of a situation where it likely makes sense to use `eval`.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: in that case, why `eval` if we can `compile` and then `funcall`?

Answer (score 15):

IMO, **this question is not specific to LISP**. Here is an answer on the same question for PHP, and it applies to LISP, Ruby, and other other language that has an eval:

> The main problems with eval() are:
>
> - **Potential unsafe input.** Passing an untrusted parameter is a way to
>     fail. It is often not a trivial task
>     to make sure that a parameter (or part
>     of it) is fully trusted.
> - **Trickyness.** Using eval() makes code clever, therefore more difficult
>     to follow. To quote Brian Kernighan
>     "*Debugging is twice as hard as
>     writing the code in the first place.
>     Therefore, if you write the code as
>     cleverly as possible, you are, by
>     definition, not smart enough to debug
>     it*"
>
> The main problem with actual use of
>   eval() is only one:
>
> - inexperienced developers who use it without enough consideration.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

I think the trickyness piece is an amazing point. The obsession with code golf and concise code has always resulted in "clever" code (for which evals are a great tool). But you should write your code for readability, IMO, not to demonstrate that you're a smarty and **not to save paper** (you won't be printing it anyway).

Then in LISP there's some problem related to the context in which eval is run, so untrusted code could get access to more things; this problem seems to be common anyway.

Comment: The "evil input" problem with EVAL only affects non-Lisp languages, because in those languages, eval() typically takes a string argument, and the user's input is typically spliced in. The user can include a quote in their input and escape into the generated code. But in Lisp, EVAL's argument is not a string, and user input cannot escape into the code unless you're absolutely reckless (as in you parsed the input with READ-FROM-STRING to create an S-expression, which you then include in the EVAL code without quoting it. If you do quote it, there's no way to escape the quote).

Answer (score 12):

The canonical answer is to stay away.  Which I find weird, because it's a primitive, and of the seven primitives (the others being cons, car, cdr, if, eq and quote), it gets far and away the least amount of use and love.

From *On Lisp*: "Usually, calling eval explicitly is like buying something in an airport gift-shop. Having waited till the last moment, you have to pay high prices for a limited selection of second-rate goods."

So when do I use eval?  One normal use is to have an REPL within your REPL by evaluating `(loop (print (eval (read))))`.  Everyone is fine with that use.

But you can also define functions in terms of macros that will be evaluated *after* compilation by combining eval with backquote.  You go

```
(eval `(macro ,arg0 ,arg1 ,arg2))))
```

and it will kill the context for you.

Swank (for emacs slime) is full of these cases.  They look like this:

```
(defun toggle-trace-aux (fspec &rest args)
  (cond ((member fspec (eval '(trace)) :test #'equal)
         (eval `(untrace ,fspec))
         (format nil "~S is now untraced." fspec))
        (t
         (eval `(trace ,@(if args `(:encapsulate nil) (list)) ,fspec ,@args))
         (format nil "~S is now traced." fspec))))
```

I don't think it's a filthy hack.  I use it all the time myself to reintegrate macros into functions.

Comment: You may want to check out the kernel language ;)

Answer (score 12):

There have been many great answers but here is another take from Matthew Flatt, one of the implementers of Racket:

http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html

He makes many of the points that have already been covered but some people may find his take interesting nonetheless.

Summary: The context in which it's used affects the result of eval but is often not considered by programmers, leading to unexpected results.

Answer (score 7):

Another couple of points on Lisp eval :

- It evaluates under the global environment, losing your local context.
- Sometimes you may be tempted to use eval, when you really meant to use the read-macro '#.'  which evaluates at read-time.

Comment: I understand that the use of global env is true for both Common Lisp and Scheme; is it also true for Clojure?

Comment: In Scheme (at least for R7RS, perhaps also for R6RS) you must pass an environment to eval.

Answer (score 4):

Like the GOTO "rule": If you don't know what you are doing, you can make a mess.

Besides from only building something out of known and safe data, there's the problem that some languages/implementations can't optimize the code enough. You could end up with interpreted code inside `eval`.

Comment: What does that rule have to do with GOTO?  Is there any feature in any programming language with which you *can't* make a mess?

Comment: @Ken: There is no GOTO rule, hence the quotation marks in my answer. There's just a dogma for people who are afraid to think for themselves. Same for eval. I remember speeding up some Perl script dramatically by using eval. It's one tool in your toolbox. Newbies often use eval when other language constructs are easier/better. But avoiding it completely just to be cool and please dogmatic people?

Answer (score 4):

Eval is just unsecure.
For example you have following code:

```
eval('
hello('.$_GET['user'].');
');
```

Now user comes to your site and enters url http://example.com/file.php?user=);$is_admin=true;echo(

Then the resulting code would be:

```
hello();$is_admin=true;echo();
```

Comment: he was talking about Lisp thought not php

Comment: @fmsf He was talking specifically about Lisp but generally about `eval` in any language that has it.

Comment: @fmsf - this is actually a language-independent question. It even applies to static compiled languages as they can simulate eval by calling out to the compiler at runtime.

Comment: "Just unsecure?" is kind of throwing the baby out with the bathwater (assuming you want the baby :)). Doing an eval on user inputted strings is so obviously stupid it's probably not worth mentioning. On the other hand, trying to sanitize those strings is probably a difficult exercise.

Comment: in that case the language is a duplicate. I've seen lots like this one arround here.

Comment: @fmsf "The [question] is a duplicate"?

Comment: @yar yeah the question sry :P my bad

Comment: PHP eval is not like Lisp eval. Look, it operates on a character string, and the exploit in the URL depends on being able to close a textual parenthesis and open another one. Lisp eval is not susceptible to this kind of stuff. You can eval data that comes as input from a network, if you sandbox it properly (and the structure is easy enough to walk in order to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Eval is not evil. Eval is not complicated. It is a function that compiles the list you pass to it. In most other languages, compiling arbitrary code would mean learning the language's AST and digging around in the compiler internals to figure out the compiler API. In lisp, you just call eval.

When should you use it? Whenever you need to compile something, typically a program that accepts, generates or modifies *arbitrary code at runtime*.

When shouldn't you use it? All other cases.

Why shouldn't you use it when you don't need to? Because you would be doing something in an unnecessarily complicated way that may cause problems for readability, performance and debugging.

Yeah, but if I'm a beginner how do I know if I should use it? Always try to implement what you need with functions. If that doesn't work, add macros. If that still doesn't work, then eval!

Follow these rules and you'll never do evil with eval :)

Answer (score 0):

I like [Zak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574219/31818) very much and he has gotten at the essence of the matter: *eval* is used when you are writing a new language, a script, or modification of a language. He doesn't really explain further so I will give an example:

```
(eval (read-line))
```

In this simple Lisp program, the user is prompted for input and then whatever they enter is evaluated. For this to work the *entire* set of symbol definitions has to be present if the program is compiled, because you have no idea which functions the user might enter, so you have to include them all. That means that if you compile this simple program, the resulting binary will be gigantic.

As a matter of principle, you can't even consider this a compilable statement for this reason. In general, once you use *eval*, you are operating in an interpreted environment, and the code can no longer be compiled. If you do not use *eval* then you can compile a Lisp or Scheme program just like a C program. Therefore, you want to make sure you want and need to be in an interpreted environment before committing to using *eval*.