# what is error in this eval code?

Tags: php, eval

```
 eval('class this {  ');

 eval('function this($l1,$l2) {
  if($l1==0) { throw new ErrorException("error"); }
  echo $l1.$l2;
  }}');

try {
 $t = new this(0,1);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Why is this code not working?

### Errors:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_FUNCTION in .......(4) : eval()'d code on line 1

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in.......(9) : eval()'d code on line 4

Fatal error: Class 'this' not found in .......on line 12
```

Comment: The error is that use `eval`. It's not the error PHP is complaining about, but it's still the real error.

Comment: Any reason to use `eval` here?

Comment: @zerkms... just learning

Comment: @mrNepal: it is not thing you should ever use, though. My opinion is that you're just wasting your time now.

Comment: I'd say: Before you learn `eval` (or even learn about it), you should learn everything else in the language, very well, so you know how to solve that problems that seem to be solved "easily" by `eval` without it, i.e. better.

Comment: I asked about the error in my code, Does that deserve a `down vote`, I am not asking you whether eval should be used or not, so please keep your opinions to yourself, i asked a question and i would like if you answer it rather that lecturing me?

Comment: Such a command tone! What if I refuse to keep my opinion to myself? You gonna fire me? Why don't you like a lecture or two anyway? What's wrong in learning something useful?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel... that comment was intended for the downvoter, I dont think I deserve a downvote for asking about the error at my code, no matter how much useless that piece of code is. As I have mentioned time to time her, I am also trying to learn something.....

Comment: Why you are so anxious for the vote? Does it matter anything? Still i see no reason to command enyone, even the downvoter. This is free site, and anyone can do anything as long as it fits the rules.

Comment: But to be fair, the downvote is imo not warranted. @mrNepal: See e.g. [Why exactly is eval evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil), although asked for Lisp, most applies to all languages (just ignore macros and add associative arrays/(hash)maps instead in the top answer's explanation why you don't need `eval`)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, being on free country does not mean going to a singing club and start dancing, does it?

Comment: Oh. You're taking a downvote THAT seriously? Poor boy

Comment: @mrNepal FYI, senseless profanity has no place here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `eval()` an unclosed statement like `class this {`. You'd have to put the entire block into one string and run the `eval()` once.

That said, there is probably no reason to use `eval()` in the first place. What are you trying to do?

Comment: How can i do, what i am trying do up there?

Comment: @mrNepal what *are* you trying to do up there? :) Why not simply put the code into the normal flow without eval()?

Answer (score 2):

`eval` accepts **complete and valid** piece of php code. `class this {` is not valid, bacause there is no `}` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Like Pekka said, though you could append the code to `eval()` in a variable like so:

```
$textToEval = 'class this {  ';
$textToEval .= 'function this($l1,$l2) {
     if($l1==0) { throw new ErrorException("error"); }
     echo $l1.$l2;
     }}';
eval($textToEval);
```

Comment: Hush! Even though you are technically right, such information should at least be preceded by a large sermon on the evilness of `eval` unless it's clear that OP knows them and showed that its use is justified.