# Python won't eval() code

Tags: python

I have the following eval() thing:

```
c = Customer()
eval("c.name = row.value('customer', '{c}')".format(c=column_name), { 'c': c, 'row': row})
```

When I try to run that, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import.py", line 19, in <module>
    c = Customer.save_from_row(row)
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/customer.py", line 43, in save_from_row
    eval("c.name = row.value('customer', '{c}')".format(c=column_name), { 'c': c, 'row': row})
  File "<string>", line 1
    c.name = row.value('customer', 'name')
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Because it looks like I didn't explain the context of my problem well enough, here's what I ended up doing, if anyone's curious:

```
@classmethod
def save_from_row(cls, row):
    c = cls()
    map(lambda column_name: setattr(c, column_name, row.value('customer', column_name)), c.distinguishing_column_names())
    return c.upsert()
```

Before I found out about `setattr()` I was separately setting several different attributes on `c`.

Comment: So... what's wrong with `c.name = row.value('customer', column_name)`?  Why get `eval()` involved?

Comment: Because I have a whole list of different column names and properties of `Customer` that I need to assign.

Comment: Why not use `getattr` and `setattr`?

Comment: Because I didn't know about them. I tried `setattr` and it did exactly what I wanted. If you post `setattr` as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`eval` evaluates *expressions*. Assignment is a statement, not an expression.

And don't even get me started on how easily misused and - in 99.99% of all cases - utterly unnecesary `eval` is. Just refer to the numerous other `eval` questions, I bet each has at least one such rant in an answer or comment - so I'll save my breath and link to [one I like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil). (That being said, `exec` works like `eval` for statements.)

Comment: Any recommendation for what I might do instead of eval?

Comment: @Jason: Depends on what you need. In general, if you are emulating [PHP's variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) - i.e. associate values with strings - a dictionary will do work as well while preserving sanity (and be orders of magnitude faster while we're at it).

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this do what you need?:

```
c = Customer()
name_cols = (('name', 'custname'), ('addr', 'cust_addr'))
for name, col in name_cols:
    setattr(c, name, row.value('customer', col))
```