# Mapped calls to clojurescript macro

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

I don't write macros particularly often.  I have never been in this situation, where I would like to `defn` a number of functions based on information known at compile time, from a vector.  The use case is creating a wrapper lib in clojurescript for a JS library, where there are a number of methods on a JS object which I'd like to wrap with more idiomatic cljs functions.

Unlike [clojure macro to generate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852351/clojure-macro-to-generate-functions) this question hinges on the macro being called with a non-literal argument, which is passed into the macro as a form (not evaluated), which must then be evaluated before the macro can return a code form.

Below, the individual call to `defevent` works as expected, creating a function in the `core` ns for `on-x`.  However, when called in the `map`, operating on `events`, a vector of keywords, it fails with:

```
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var foo.core/defevent at line 1 <cljs repl>
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1' of undefined
```

I suspect this is because macros receive arguments as unevaluated forms, and somewhere in the `map` source, my `defevent` is called with a form more-or-less like `(defevent (rest foo))` or somesuch... So how would I rewrite `defevent`, or the the `(map defevent events)` code to enable `defn`'ing functions based on the values in `events`?

macros.clj:

```
(ns foo.macros)

(defmacro defevent
  [event-kw]
  `(defn ~(symbol (str "on-" (name event-kw)))
     [~'this ~'keyvec ~'cb]
     (.call (aget ~'this ~(name event-kw))
            ~'this
            ~'keyvec
            ~'cb)))
```

core.cljs:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require-macros [foo.macros :refer [defevent]])

(defevent :x) ;; works

(def events [:a :b :c])
(doall (map defevent events)) ;; fails
```

Comment: This question is different than the referenced "duplicate".  I edited to show the difference.

Comment: You have run into a big limitation of macros: a macro cannot be used as an argument go another function. Please see "Macros All the Way Down" at http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/

Comment: Thanks Alan.  The approach in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904628/how-to-create-clojure-defn-functions-automatically/43904717#43904717 will not work because clojurescript doesn't have `intern`.

Comment: I re-worked the answer to make it clearer (hopefully) and added the all-macro solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958471/how-to-create-clojure-defn-functions-automatically-without-macros  The other alternative (#3) is to just make a new (anonymous) wrapper fn and register it each time. May be the easiest solution in CLJS