# Why are "dotted pair" s-expressions allowed in Racket syntax?

Tags: scheme, racket

After more or less understanding the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631001/), it looks to me that in Racket/Scheme, at the reader level, the second element of each pair in the syntax tree has to be a list.  In other words, whenever a dotted s-expression of the form `(A . B)` represents a vertex of the syntax tree, `B` can only by an s-expression that parses as a list, like `(C D E)`. For example: `(A . (C D E))`.  This of course can be written as `(A C D E)`, because it is parsed identically.

```lisp
(+ . (1 2 3)) ; => 6
(+ 1 2 3) ; => 6

(define . (x 1))
x ; => 1
(define y 2)
y ; => 2
```

My question is: what is the reason that "dotted pair" s-expressions are allowed in the Racket/Scheme syntax, other than inside literal data?  Is there an example of a Racket/Scheme expression that can be written using pairs, but cannot be written simpler using lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any Lisp system, reading and evaluating are separate steps. To the reader, *everything* is literal data; it's the evaluator that decides what to evaluate and what (by virtue of `quote` and `quasiquote`) to treat as literal data.

The reader reads the following expressions exactly the same way:

```
(+ 1 2 3)
(+ . (1 2 3))
(+ . (1 . (2 3)))
(+ . (1 . (2 . (3))))
(+ . (1 . (2 . (3 . ()))))
```

This is because, at the basic level, non-empty lists are made up of a bunch of cons cells, which happen to have a `cdr` that points to another list (empty or not).

Furthermore, there *are* legitimate Scheme expressions that do use improper lists. Rest arguments for lambdas are a prime example of this:

```
(define (list . items)
  items)
```

Comment: Any Lisp system, except Clojure ;p

Comment: Nope `.` is a symbol (there are no 'pairs' in Clojure) O_o (also `,` is basically a whitespace)