# GUI Table using in Racket / variable parameters using list-box%

Tags: user-interface, listbox, scheme, racket

I'm currently trying to create a a grid of information in Racket using the Racket Graphical Interface Tooling. The only real table that is available is the list-box% ([link to reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/list-box_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred/main..rkt%29._list-box~25%29._set%29%29))

To fill the table I need to use:

```
 (send a-list-box set choices ...) → void?
      choices : (listof label-string?)
```

choices being list being a list of each column. The problem is that I have a variable amount of collumns. My current data is formated like `(list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))`.
The **goal is te execute this command**: `(send table set (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6)`

**What I already tried**

I made a function witch gives me this output: `"(list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6)"` 
The idea was to then execute this string command using:

`(send table set (eval (call-with-input-string "(list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6)" read)`

I also tried  this:

`(eval (call-with-input-string "(send table set (list  1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))" read)`
But this gives me an error `table: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition`

**If you don't see a problem but now an other way to display a grid of data in racket using the build in GUI, please share. Thanks**

**Test Code**

```
`#lang racket
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% 
                  [label "myTable"]
                  [width 800]
                  [height 600]
                  ))

(define table (new list-box%
                 [parent frame]
                 [choices (list )]
                 [label "Test"]
                 [style (list 'single 'column-headers 'variable-columns)]
                 [columns (list "C1" "C2" "C3")]))

(define data (list (list "1" "2" "3")
                   (list "4" "5" "6")
                   (list "6" "8" "9")))


(send table set (list-ref data 0) (list-ref data 1) (list-ref data 2));--> Works but needs to be aple to handle variable lengtho of data
;(apply send table set data) ;--> ERROR: send: bad syntax

;(map (lambda (element)
;             (send table set element)) ;--> ERROR: set in list-box%: column count doesn't match argument count  column count: 3  argument count: 1
;     data)

(send frame show #t)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [`send/apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html?q=send&q=set#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._send%2Fapply%29%29) is what you want.

```
(send/apply table set data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define your-listbox-var (new list-box%
                      (label "")
                      (parent YOUR MAIN FRAME OR NULL)
                      (choices '("" "" "") )
                      (style (list 'single ; je kunt ze nog veranderen
                                   'variable-columns
                                   'column-headers))
                      (columns (list "Column1" "Column2" "Column3" ))))
```

If you define your variabele in this way, and if you call

```
(send your-listbox-var set  (list 1 2 3)  (list 1 2 3))
```

AFTER the definition of variabele, it will work.

Comment: The problem is in my code I get the data as `(define data (list (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))` If I then do `(send table set data)` it wont work. I need to get all the lists out of the data variable but can't find a way to do this.

Comment: you have to send the lists separately. In your case; '(send table set (car data) (cadr data))'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define data '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
(apply send table set data) ; same as (send table set '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

Use [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) when your input arguments arrive in a list of unknown size and the procedure accepts a variable number of parameters. For a simpler example:

```
(define data '(1 2 3))
(apply + data) ; same as (+ 1 2 3)
=> 6
```

You can imagine that `apply` "removes" the extra parenthesis around its last argument, so that this: `(apply + '(1 2 3))` becomes this: `(+ 1 2 3)`.

**UPDATE**

Given that `send` is a *macro* and not a *procedure* as I had incorrectly assumed, the above won't work. I came up with a solution I'm not proud of, using `eval` (which is [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil)) and list splicing - I hope someone can suggest a cleaner solution, but this will work:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))
(eval `(send table set ,@'data) ns)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Getting bad syntax error for send. I added a piece of test file code to the first post where I'm testing possible solutions. apply seems like a good idea so will try to fix the error

Comment: Ugh, that happens because `send` it's not a procedure, but a macro. Then `apply` won't work, and a macro must be used in its place

Comment: Ok so I need to write my own macro to do this? What should this macro do? Never did it so I'll start reading the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble. For the moment I fixed it by using a big `cond` witch manually does executes the the `(send ...)` for a list not bigger then 10. Not very pretty and not good code but works for now.

Comment: @Timbo925 I figured out a workaround, using `eval`. See my updated answer.

Comment: To avoid the `eval` you can use `dynamic-send`.