# How to eval twice in lisp (without using eval)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval

How can I eval something a second time while keeping the lexical context?

```
* (defvar form '(+ 1 2))
form
* form
(+ 1 2)
* (eval form) ;; This loses the lexical scope (not an issue here)
3
```

For an example of the problem where the lexical scope is needed

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2)
      (form '(+ a b)))
  (print form)
  (print (eval form))  )
(+ a b) 
The variable A is unbound.
```

How do I eval that form twice in the same lexical scope?

How do eval as many times I as want (in the same lexical scope)?

Related to a previous question
[Why does SBCL eval function lose the macrolet it's running in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483503/why-does-sbcl-eval-function-lose-the-macrolet-its-running-in)

Comment: The standard `eval` doesn't let you evaluate a form in any but the null lexical environment.  What do you mean by "eval twice"?  You can certainly apply `eval` to the result of a call to `eval`, but I doubt that's what you mean?  Can you show an example of what you'd like to be able to do, and explain how it "evals twice"?

Comment: Also, is this related to your earlier question, [Why does SBCL eval function lose the macrolet it's running in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483503/why-does-sbcl-eval-function-lose-the-macrolet-its-running-in), in which you accepted the answer that says that eval doesn't work with lexical environments?

Comment: check out 'pandoric-eval' in LOL: http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap6.html#sec_7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can be mistaken, but this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I guess your example is so simplified that the reason for your request has disappeared. Why do you need this?

Without knowing more I'm thinking you might solve this with a macro:

```lisp
(defun run (expr)
  (funcall expr :run))

(defun src (expr)
  (funcall expr :src))

(defmacro expr (&body rest)
  `(let ((run (lambda () ,@rest))
         (src ',@rest))
     (lambda (m)
       (case m
         (:run (funcall run))
         (otherwise src))))))
```

Instead of quoting your code you feed it to `expr` and it creates an object. The two functions `run` and `src` takes this object and either run it in the original lexical environment (since I created a thunk) or return the source of the expression. You'r example would then be written as:

```lisp
(let* ((a 1) 
       (b 2)
       (form (expr (+ a b))))
  (print (src form))
  (print (run form)))
```

Notice I changed from `let` to `let*` since neither `a` nor `b` is available for `form`. Thus the lexical environment you get is the same as if you would run your code in place of the `expr` form.

Eval is not used once nor twice. Perhaps `CLOS` could have worked just as nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use eval to evalute a form in a lexical scope.  Quoth the HyperSpec page on eval (emphasis added):

> ### [Function EVAL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm)
>
> #### Syntax:
>
> **eval** *form* ⇒ *result**
>
> #### Arguments and Values:
>
> - *form*—a form.
> - *results*—the values yielded by the evaluation of *form*.
>
> #### Description:
>
> Evaluates form in the current dynamic environment ***and the null lexical
>   environment***.

### Implementations with evaluation in environment support

Although the standard `eval` doesn't allow you to specify a lexical environment, some implementations may provide this functionality in an implementation defined manner.  For example

#### CLISP's `ext:eval-env`

> #### [3.1. Evaluation](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/evaluation.html)
>
> Function (EXT:EVAL-ENV form &OPTIONAL environment). evaluates a form
>   in a given lexical environment, just as if the form had been a part of
>   the program that the environment came from.

Comment: Yes, that was my question: How to eval twice in lisp (without using eval).  I know I can't use eval, but what about some sort of macro, or apply, or funcall trick... or are you telling me it's impossible?  .. I know it's not impossible, it's just a matter of how awkward is it.

Comment: I understand what you mean by eval'ing in a lexical environment.  You can't do that.  I don't know what you mean by  "eval twice".  You can do, e.g., `(eval (eval '(list '+ 1 2)))` and quite literally eval twice, but I doubt that that's what you mean.

Comment: Outside of the debugger, there is no function you can call that can access the value of a lexical variable, given its name.

Comment: Xach -- That's a big part of the answer I was looking for (but didn't know it).  
(let ((form '(+ a b))) (let ((a 1) (b 2)) (apply (car form) (cdr form)))) .. but there is no way to eval a and b at that point... not that can see the a=1 b=2.

Comment: This answer (eval uses the null lexical environment) doesn't really address my issue (and it seems there is no way to address this issue... almost like that's what a *lexical* environment is for ;-)