# How to construct a function from a list of functions and a value?

Tags: function, macros, clojure

I'm trying to build a function out of the results of one already evaluated function and a list of other functions. If I partially construct it it works fine, but every time I try to construct the entire thing it fails.

```
(defn play [] 
    (let [eval1 (eval '(+ 1 1))]
        (eval `(->> ~eval1 (+ 5) (- 2) (* 7)))
    )
)
```

This fails:

```
(defn play []
    (let [eval1 (eval '(+ 1 1))
          eval2 '((+ 5) (- 2) (* 7))]
        (eval (cons (cons eval1 eval2) ->>))
     )
)
```

I've tried numerous other ways to put this together and I think it boils down to me not quite understanding this aspect of clojure.  What's the best way to go about this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: ->> is a macro. You can not take the value of a macro into an eval-function because macros only exist in the compile-time context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You generally don't want to use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil?lq=1). However, maybe this time you do, for whatever reason (understanding Clojure's reader is a valid reason). So the answer depends on what you mean by "this problem."

**Part 1 -- with eval**

A. Webb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766600/2472391) is perfectly fine. If the example you gave is just so you can learn how the Clojure reader works, the rest of my answer may be irrelevant to you.

**Part 2 -- without eval**

If by "this problem" you mean constructing a function from a list of functions and a value, you don't want `eval`. Replace `(eval '(+ 1 1))` with `(+ 1 1)`. Then because you want a list of functions, you can use [`#(+ 5 %)`](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) etc. or [`(partial + 5)`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partial) etc. and store those in a list.

[`->>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is a threading macro. This means it is executed at compile time, to transform its whole S-expression. But in your failed code, it doesn't have an S-expression at compile time -- you would be attempting to craft its S-expression *at run time* by `cons`ing it onto another list.

You could write another macro to do what you want here. But in general, when I confront the problem of applying a list of functions to an initial value, I use [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce):

```
(defn play []
    (let [eval1 (+ 1 1)
          eval2 (list #(+ 5 %) #(- 2 %) #(* 7 %))]
        (reduce #(%2 %) eval1 eval2)))
```

In fact, this comes up often enough in my code that most of my projects have this in their core.clj:

```
(defn freduce
   "Given an initial input and a collection of functions (f1,..,fn),
   This is logically equivalent to ((comp fn ... f1) input)."
   [in fs]
   (reduce #(%2 %) in fs))
```

Finally, if you want to construct *a function* rather than its evaluation, then wrap the return value with [`fn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/fn):

```
(defn play []
    (let [in (+ 1 1)
          fs (list #(+ 5 %) #(- 2 %) #(* 7 %))]
        (fn [] (freduce in fs))))

user=> ((play))
-35
```

Comment: The first bit is perhaps misleading out of context. In general, you would be working with symbols doing compile-time manipulation. Happily, symbols resolving to macros within the body of other macros work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, the second part of your answer describes exactly the problem I was aiming to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The two problems at hand with your second `play` are (1) you have not quoted `->>` so Clojure will complain about "tak[ing] the value of a macro", you want to be doing symbolic manipulation instead; and (2) you are `cons`ing your list together in the wrong order.

Try

```
(defn play []
  (let [eval1 (eval '(+ 1 1))
        eval2 '((+ 5) (- 2) (* 7))]
    (eval (cons '->> (cons eval1 eval2)))))
```

Other things to consider would be to use normal functions or macros, use syntax quote to capture namespaces, use `list*` instead of two `cons`.

Answer (score 0):

`(+ 1 1)` is not a function, `'((+ 5) (- 2) (* 7))` is not a list of functions.

If you have a list of functions, say

```
(def fns (list (partial + 5) (fn [x] (- 2 x)) #(* 7 %)))
```

you can achieve your goal of "constructing a function from a list of functions"

```
(def master-fn (->> fns reverse (apply comp)))
```

Then you can invoke it with "the result of one already evaluated function [call]":

```
(master-fn (+ 1 1))
;; => -35
```