# Try to use a parameter in a list like a function name in Scheme

Tags: list, function, scheme, racket

I have a list like that -> `(define l '(at1 at2 at3))` where `at1` is the name of a function. When I try to put that value as the name of a function (i.e. `(at1 value1 value2)`), I obtain this:

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments

because `at1` is a list (`'valueofat1`). I'm trying to use `apply` and `list->string`, but both aren't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I use the value of a list in a given position as a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you definitely want to use a list of symbols representing function names you can use [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) and [`eval`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html), but beware: [`eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil) and you should avoid using it!

```
; some functions
(define (at1 x y) (+ x y))
(define (at2 x y) (- x y))
(define (at3 x y) (* x y))

; a list of symbols named like the functions
(define lst '(at1 at2 at3))

; operands
(define value1 30)
(define value2 12)

; obtain evaluation namespace
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

; apply the first function from the list of function names
(apply (eval (car lst) ns) (list value1 value2))
         ^                          ^
 evaluate operator           list of operands
```

The above will return `42`. I have the feeling that you're struggling with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you *really* trying to accomplish? wouldn't it be a better idea to use a list of *functions* instead of a list of *symbols* representing function names? I mean, like this:

```
; some functions
(define (at1 x y) (+ x y))
(define (at2 x y) (- x y))
(define (at3 x y) (* x y))

; a list of functions
(define lst (list at1 at2 at3))

; operands
(define value1 30)
(define value2 12)

; apply the first function from the list of functions
((car lst) value1 value2)
=> 42
```

Comment: That's you show it's that I have, but if I try to use the `apply` form, it isn't working. The `at1` function is defined, and `lst` is created after that. It's still giving the same error as I tell you U_U I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Now it works! I've used `apply`and `eval` together, like the first example you put. Now I have to investigate about namespace-anchor and those things, because I don't know how it is. Thank you so much.