# why is it useful to treat code as data in lisp

Tags: emacs, macros, lisp, eval, homoiconicity

I learn emacs lisp now and I wonder why it maybe useful to treat code as data. What a benefits of this approach. I saw one explanation as this is alternative to traditional **Von Neumann architecture** where exists clear separattion between data and code. 
I'd like to understand a meaning for this decision, get the idea.

Thanks in advance, Nick.

Comment: Construct and return functions at runtime. Pass them as parameters to other functions. Think about mapcar where the first arg could be a lisp function you construct at runtime, based on a specific context.

Comment: Code as data is not so much about returning functions at runtime or passing them as parameters, that's a higher-order language feature, found in ML too. Code as data can be useful in many situations, I suggest reading some Paul Graham on the matter. 
What can you do with code as data? You can do macros! In lisp, a new "statement" like while, if, try/catch, can be written as a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write code that will write code for you. This can be done in two ways:

- First, your program can create new code as a list and pass it to the `eval` function, which will evaluate the new code at runtime (however, `eval` is something you should not abuse -- actually, it should be used seldomly, when you really need it). You could theoretically do this in languages that do not have the homoiconicity property, but it would be a lot harder. 
  For example, in Scheme you may do this

```lisp
(define form '(x 10))
(set! form (append 'define form)
(eval form (interaction-environment)
```

and the value of `x` will be 10 after that. This could be used, for example, in [Genetic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming)

- You may also define macros. A macro is a little function that reads something that *looks like* a function call, but is translated (expanded) into something else *before the program starts evaluating forms* (that is, before it is run). For example, in many Lisps `or` is a macro. This code,

```lisp
(or a b c)
```

is translated into

```lisp
(let ((tmp1 a))
  (if tmp1
      tmp1
      (let ((tmp2 b))
        (if tmp2
            tmp2
            (let ((tmp3 c))
              (if tmp3
                  tmp3
                  #f))))))
```

You could implement `or` as a function, but then the function would have to evaluate all its arguments before returning. Since `or` is a macro, it will not necessarily evaluate all arguments.

You can read more about macros [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29) and in [this cool book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html) [ beside several other places on the net, like [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/scheme-repository/R4RS/r4rs_12.html), 
[here](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/cs345/schintro-v13/schintro_130.html) and [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~gfb/scheme/simple-macros.html) for example ]. And you can read about eval [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) and in [this great book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node77.html).

You can also read Paul Graham's [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) (the book is completely free), which teaches basic Common Lisp in a somewhat fast pace and then gets into all kinds of programming techniques with macros, and later you can try [Let Over Lambda](http://letoverlambda.com/) (only some chapters are free).

About `eval` it may be interestig to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil) and its answers.

Comment: I didn't expect such good explanation. Thanks.