# Indetifying nested quotes and unquote it in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a special folding function.

I have a problem regarding quotes, Especially them nested ones. It seems like they are sometimes interpeted as the start of a list, And sometimes as a quote.

Say i've got the next code:

```
'(x '(a b c))
```

Then:

```
(car '(x '(a b c)))
```

Will return: x. While:

```
(cadr '(x '(a b c)))
```

Will return: '(a b c).
 What does this mean? Is this a list? if so why does:

```
(caadr '(x '(a b c)))
```

Returns: quote. What is the meanning of this quote?
Is there any way to indentify those kind of lists? And if so, Is there any way to unquote them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we're evaluating a quoted expression, remember that this expression: `'x` is just shorthand for this: `(quote x)`. For example:

```
'(x '(a b c))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(quote (x (quote (a b c))))
```

Now this expression will also return a quoted expression, which happens to start with *yet another* quoted expression:

```
(cadr (quote (x (quote (a b c)))))
                ---------------
=> ''(a b c)
```

This is more apparent in the next example, where we end up retrieving the `'quote` symbol itself:

```
(caadr (quote (x (quote (a b c)))))
                  -----
=> 'quote
```

For the last part of the question: if you want to interpret the innermost list as a *list* and not as a quoted expression, then don't quote it at all:

```
(cadr '(x (a b c)))
=> '(a b c)
```

Of course, we could also leave the second `quote` and `eval` the innermost list, but that's a hassle and [potentially evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil):

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(eval (cadr '(x '(a b c))) ns)
=> '(a b c)
```

Or we could use [quasiquoting and unquoting](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._unquote%29%29):

```
(cadr `(x ,'(a b c)))
=> '(a b c)
```

Comment: @StationaryTraveller great! please see my last edit, for some extra clarifications