# Lisp: why did `eval` lose favor after lexical scoping was introduced?

Tags: lisp, eval

Just came across a quote from Peter Norvig in Paradigms in AI Programing:

> In the past, eval was seen as the key to Lisp's flexibility. In
>   modern Lisps with lexical scoping, such as Common Lisp, eval is used
>   less often (in fact, in Scheme there is no eval at all). Instead,
>   programmers are expected to use lambda to create a new function, and
>   then apply or funcall the function.

There are considerations on why eval is not a good idea, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil), however I am more interested in the interaction between `eval` and dynamic (special?) variables and how introduction of lexicals contributed to `eval` losing favor. What were some common `eval` idioms before the introduction of lexical variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have a citation handy, but from what I remember hearing, the pattern that that text might be referring to is a way to *emulate* lexical scoping. That is, in lexical Common Lisp, we can simply write:

```
(defun constant-adder (a)
  (lambda (b) (+ a b)))
```

In a language which used dynamic scope for all variables (but with the same syntax otherwise), lexical scope could be emulated by constructing a lambda expression:

```
(defun constant-adder (a)
  (eval `(lambda (b) (+ (quote ,a) b))))
```

That is, we are constructing at runtime an expression which has *the value of `a` substituted in*, rather than having the language capture `a` automatically.

(However, your quote suggests that there was also no `lambda` in use. I have no plausible explanations for what would be happening in that case.)

Comment: This is similar to how it's [still done in picolisp](http://software-lab.de/doc/faq.html#closures).

Answer (score 1):

[`eval`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm)

> Evaluates form in the current dynamic environment and the **null lexical environment**.

This means that

```
(defun f (a) (eval '(1+ a)))
; warning: The variable A is defined but never used.
```

The compiler notices that, contrary to a naive expectation, `a` is *not* passed to `eval`.
Indeed:

```
(f 10)
; error: UNBOUND-VARIABLE: The variable A is unbound.
```