# How to get a text to be executed in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Suppose that the following macro execution:

```
(make-model '((1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8)))
```

, can generate the following list:

```
((MAKE-INSTANCE 'MODEL :NAME 7 :ID 8) 
 (MAKE-INSTANCE 'MODEL :NAME 5 :ID 6)
 (MAKE-INSTANCE 'MODEL :NAME 3 :ID 4) 
 (MAKE-INSTANCE 'MODEL :NAME 1 :ID 2))
```

If I store the result in a parameter (e.g *test*), how could I get lisp to execute the four commands in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm):

```
(mapcar #'eval *test*)
```

However, this is a [suboptimal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2571401/850781).

You would be much better off saving either a lambda:

```
(defmacro make-model-lambda (args)
  (list* 'lambda () (apply #'make-model args)))
(defparameter *test* (make-model-lambda ....))
(funcall *test*)
```

or just the list of args themselves:

```
(defparameter *test*
  (mapcar (lambda (name-id)
            (list 'model :name (first name-id) :id (second name-id)))
          '((1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 8))))
(mapcar #'apply *test*)
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I think I understand the principle now.

Comment: I'm a little lost regarding the dot notation inside the backquote form. isnt that going to result in `(lambda () make-model ..whatever-args-evald-to))` ? or is it meant to be a comma?