# Lisp SBCL macro quoted list as parameter

Tags: macros, common-lisp, quote

Say I have a macro like

```
(defmacro repeat (times &body body)
 (let ((x (gensym)))
  `(dotimes (,x ,times)
    ,@body)))
```

Then I can run on the repl

```
CL-USER> (repeat 2 (print "Hi"))

"Hi"
"Hi"
NIL
```

If I run

```
CL-USER> (list 'print "Hi")
(PRINT "Hi")
```

So why can't I run

```
CL-USER> (repeat 2 (list 'print "hi"))
NIL
```

The backquote just gives me a list doesn't it? Is that not the same as what gets passed to the body parameter when I do not use a backquote (a list of s-expressions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, it just doesn't do what you think it should.

`(repeat 2 (print "Hi"))` evaluates its second argument twice, so it prints `"Hi"` two times. It also returns `"Hi"` twice, but `dolist`, and, thus, `repeat`, discards the return value of `print`.

`(repeat 2 (list 'print "hi"))` evaluates its second argument twice, so it creates the list `(print "hi")` twice and discards it. To have it actually *print* `"hi"`, you would have to evaluate it **two** times (once producing *code* `(print "hi")` the the second time evaluating the code to print `"hi"`).

Comment: Thanks for your response sds! Not quite what I was asking but got me on the right track!

Comment: (let ((mylist (list 'print "Hi"))) (eval `(repeat 2 ,mylist)))

Comment: PLEASE see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil regarding eval. You do not need it for this example.