# How to split a string in Python that has on its own 2 arguments

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

It's really odd but I have this string:

```
"['please', 'help']"
```

I want something that would get one argument at a time.
I've searched everywhere for this but I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `eval` is a correct approach, it can often have [negative consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil). I suggest using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which is a more safe approach (as mentioned by the linked docs):

```
import ast
s = "['please', 'help']"
s_list = ast.literal_eval(s)
print s_list
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
string = "['please', 'help']"
string_list = eval(string)

print string_list[0], string_list[1]
```

Edit: you should ideally use `ast.literal_eval` as the other answer suggests, if you are unsure of what the string contains.

Comment: WOW, yeah dude, thanks a lot