# Write name of array on the go from name + variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such array component which prints out Good.

```
console.log(nameA_componentA['abc'].aaa);
```

But now I want to print it out like this

```
var ccc='componentA';
console.log(nameA_+ccc['abc'].aaa);
```

But it's not working unfortunately :(
Where is my mistake ?

Comment: You should use Eval for such cases

Comment: in the data structure? i suggest to use objects for named parts instead of name variables with a variable part.

Comment: Assuming the object is present in the global namespace, `window['nameA_' + ccc]['abc'].aaa`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not recommended, you can do this in Javascript without having to use `eval()`. Since global variables are descendants of the `window` object, you can access them like this:

```
var ccc='componentA';
console.log(window['nameA_' + ccc]['abc'].aaa);
```

But it's probably better practice to use objects / arrays instead of using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` for such cases.

```js
var nameA_componentA = {
  abc: {
    aaa: 'Hello World'
  }
}

var ccc='componentA';
var obj = eval('nameA_'+ccc);
console.log(obj['abc'].aaa)
//console.log(nameA_+ccc['abc'].aaa);
```

**Note:** If you have option to restructure your code to wrap all such objects inside a wrapper object, you should do it. Consider `eval` as last resort.

```js
var nameA_componentA = {
  abc: {
    aaa: 'Hello World'
  }
}
var nameA_componentB = {
  abc: {
    aaa: 'Hello Foo'
  }
}

var wrapperObj = {
  nameA_componentA: nameA_componentA,
  nameA_componentB: nameA_componentB
}

var ccc='componentA';
var ccc1='componentB';
console.log( wrapperObj['nameA_'+ccc]['abc'].aaa);
console.log( wrapperObj['nameA_'+ccc1]['abc'].aaa);
```

#### References

- [Why eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil)
- [Why use of eval considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)
- [Using global variables is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `(window || context)['nameA_' + ccc].abc.aaa`

```js
const nameA_componentA = {
  abc: {
    aaa: 'Good'
  }
}
console.log(nameA_componentA['abc'].aaa);
const ccc='componentA';
// this isn't working in the stack snippets
// console.log(window['nameA_' + ccc]['abc'].aaa);

// you are better off namespacing
const nameA = {
  componentA: { abc: { aaa: 'Good' }},
  componentB: { abc: { aaa: 'Great' }}
}

console.log(nameA[ccc].abc.aaa)
```