# How to new a Class by it's string type name and apply a array parameter inside which has null value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

1. I have 2 Class defined somewhere else, all constructors need 3
   parameters (a, b, c), but a, b(object), c(object) is in an Array

   ```
   var paramArr = [a, b, c];
   ```
2. I would like to call these 2 Class via a parameter according to a dictionary object, like:

   ```
   var dict = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'};
   ```

   then,

   ```
   callClass(x){
     var className = dict[x];//string
     new className();
   }
   ```
3. So, first I tried to do is something like eval so that I could call the Class with it string name.

   ```
   callClass(x){
     var className = dict[x];//string
     var classFn = new Function(this, 'new ' + className + '()');
     classFn();
   }
   ```
4. still works fine. at last I should add the args by Fn.prototype.apply(), then I had to say all messed up:

   ```
   callClass(x){
     var className = dict[x];//string
     paramArr.unshift(null);
     var functionBodyStr = 'return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(' + className + ', '+ paramArr +'))';
     var classFn = new Function(this, functionBodyStr);
     classFn();
   }
   ```

the classFn in the console will be:

```
    function(this){
      return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Classname, , a ,[object Object],[object Object]))
    }
```

it is something I expected but not all:

first, the 'null' value in the array is converted to disappeared, which leads to 'unexpected token ,'

second, all the other objects are converted to '[object Object]', which leads to 'unexpected identifier'

So, how could I apply a array param with null value? or this is a wrong way to do this?

Comment: Please add the example of classes in your code that you are trying to invoke. If possible, create a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: the classes are not decided yet, empty ones with constructors, just normal class like: <var A = new Class({initialize : function(a, b, c){}})>, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, you are trying to create object where class/constructor name is dynamically decided. For this, you can try using `eval`.

#### Using Eval

**Idea**

- Create class/constructor name per your requirement.
- Use eval to look for this function and get its scope.
- If found, you can directly use `new fn(...)`
- If not found, it will throw error so you will have to handle this case.

```js
function MyClass1(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c
}

function MyClass2(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c
}

var classPrefix = 'MyClass';
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var functionName = classPrefix + (i % 3 + 1);
  var fn;
  try {
    fn = eval(functionName);
    result.push(new fn(i, i+1, i+2));
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(functionName + ' was not found. Please check again.')
  }
}

result.forEach(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.constructor.name, obj.a)
})
```

#### References:

- [Eval is evil](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)
- [Why exactly is eval evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil/15395890)

---

#### Using HashMap

Idea of this approach is to have a list of possible classes with a map and use it to get reference dynamically. This is better/preferred than `eval` approach but it comes with an overhead of maintaining the map.

```js
function MyClass1(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c
}

function MyClass2(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c
}

var functionMapper = {
  'MyClass1': MyClass1,
  'MyClass2': MyClass2,
}

var classPrefix = 'MyClass';
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var functionName = classPrefix + (i % 3 + 1);
  var fn = functionMapper[functionName];
  fn && result.push(new fn(i, i+1, i+2));
}

result.forEach(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.constructor.name, obj.a)
})
```

Comment: ya, your understanding is correct, that is exactly what I want to do. I use new Function(param, body) to avoid using eval :), and I don't see is how to apply the args in your snippet, that is the part I can not handle. :) can you add that part?

Comment: @FadeocKhaos Updated my answer. As I have already specified, you will receive function reference in `fn`. So you can use it like a normal function.

Comment: @FadeocKhaos Please check the update. Added hashMap approach.

Comment: Thanks for your kind and detailed answer, I tried it, simple and works, though I am still worried a bit of using Eval, I ll head to your extra links to learn about it. About my question, I thought I lost null values when convert it to string, I asked this question by writting how I am thinking to avoid asking XY question, I eager for that answer too. Anyway I ll accept yours. Thanks.