# Racket- converting daily used + - * /

Tags: racket

I have encountered a problem where I would want to evaluate a math equation, let's say a list of string `' (1 + 2)`  and convert it into (+ 1 2) so that racket can solve it. Apparently, you can not simply do `('+ 1 2)` as `'+`is not a procedure.
What are some ways to do it?

Comment: If the problem is to go from a string `"'(+ 1 2)"` then use `read` and `open-input-string`.

Answer (score 2):

After transforming the expression from infix to prefix notation, just use [`eval`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html):

```
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(eval (list '+ 1 2) ns)
=> 3
```

Of course the usual warning applies, [`eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil), etc. But it's ok for learning purposes, as long as you're aware that most of the time you should not use it in real-life programs.

Comment: @GerryG did this post answer your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, simply click on the check mark to the left ;)