# How to refresh, remake, lexical bindings on a lambda?

Tags: binding, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to see how to rebind a lexical binding, or redefine the
closure of a lambda. The expected usage of next-noun is just to call it as many times as desired with no arguments. It should return a random noun from the list, but one that has not been returned yet until the list is exhausted.

Here is the toy example I am using:

```
#lang racket

(define nouns `(time
                year
                people
                way
                day
                man))

(define (next-noun)
  (let* ([lst-nouns (shuffle nouns)]
         [func-syn 
          `(λ ()
             (let* ([n (car lst-nouns)]
                    [lst-nouns (if (null? (cdr lst-nouns))
                                   (shuffle nouns)
                                   (cdr lst-nouns))])
               (set! next-noun (eval func-syn))
               n))])
    ((eval func-syn))))
```

When trying to run it I get this error:

```
main.rkt> 
main.rkt> (next-noun)
; lst-nouns: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
;   in module: "/home/joel/projects/racket/ad_lib/main.rkt"
```

Which confuses me since there should be a binding for lst-nouns any
time (eval func-syn) is run. What's going on?

Comment: See https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html#%28part._.Local_.Scopes%29

Comment: Why do you use `eval` at all? If you only need specified `next-noun` behavior, then you get it with `(define next-noun (sequence->generator (shuffle nouns)))`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I agree that using `sequence->generator` would have been a nice solution, but how would you reset the generator with a new reshuffled list every time is consumed? `sequence->repeated-generator` just keeps returning the elements in the same order.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I do not see where OP require that list should be reshuffled when exhausted, but in that case you can use `(define next-noun (infinite-generator (for-each yield (shuffle nouns))))`.

Comment: It's right there in the code: `(if (null? (cdr lst-nouns))  (shuffle nouns)`

Comment: @PetSerAl that's a very nice solution! hope you don't mind, I added it to my post as more idiomatic alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `eval` here, at all. It's making the solution more complex (and [insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil)) than needed. Besides, the "looping" logic is incorrect, because you're not updating the position in `lst-nouns`, and anyway it gets redefined every time the procedure is called. Also, see the [link](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html#%28part._.Local_.Scopes%29) shared by Sorawee to understand why `eval` can't see local bindings.

In Scheme we try to avoid mutating state whenever possible, but for this procedure I think it's justified. The trick is to keep the state that needs to be updated inside a closure; this is one way to do it:

```
(define nouns '(time
                year
                people
                way
                day
                man))

; notice that `next-noun` gets bound to a `lambda`
; and that `lst-nouns` was defined outside of it
; so it's the same for all procedure invocations
(define next-noun
  ; store list position in a closure outside lambda
  (let ((lst-nouns '()))
    ; define `next-noun` as a no-args procedure
    (λ ()
      ; if list is empty, reset with shuffled original
      (when (null? lst-nouns)
        (set! lst-nouns (shuffle nouns)))
      ; obtain current element
      (let ((noun (car lst-nouns)))
        ; advance to next element
        (set! lst-nouns (cdr lst-nouns))
        ; return current element
        noun))))
```

@PetSerAl proposed a more idiomatic solution in the comments.  My guess is that you want to implement this from scratch, for learning purposes - but in real-life we would do something like this, using Racket's [generators](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Generators.html):

```
(require racket/generator)

(define next-noun
  (infinite-generator
   (for-each yield (shuffle nouns))))
```

Either way it works as expected - repeatedly calling `next-noun` will return all the elements in `nouns` until exhausted, at that point the list will be reshuffled and the iteration will restart:

```
(next-noun)
=> 'day
(next-noun)
=> 'time
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with `eval`. `eval` does not have lexical environment from where it is called rather it has at most the top level bindings. Eg.

```scm
(define x 12)
(let ((x 10))
  (eval '(+ x x))) ; ==> 24
```

`eval` is almost always the wrong solution and can often be replaced with closures and called directly or with `apply`. Here is what I would have done:

```scm
(define (shuffle-generator lst)
  (define shuffled (shuffle lst))
  (define (next-element)
    (when (null? shuffled)
      (set! shuffled (shuffle lst)))
    (begin0
      (car shuffled)
      (set! shuffled (cdr shuffled))))
  next-element)

(define next-int15 (shuffle-generator '(1 2 3 4 5)))
(define random-bool (shuffle-generator '(#t #f)))
(random-bool) ; ==> #f
(next-int15) ; ==> 5
(next-int15) ; ==> 4
(next-int15) ; ==> 2
(next-int15) ; ==> 1
(next-int15) ; ==> 3
(next-int15) ; ==> 3
(random-bool) ; ==> #t
(random-bool) ; ==> #t
```

The returned values are random so it's just what I got my first round. Instead of naming `next-element` one could simply just return the lambda, but the name gives information on what it does and the debugger will show the name. eg.:

```scm
next-int15 ; ==> #<procedure:next-element>
```