# How to read a slot from an object reference, without evaluating the pointer

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, symbols, evaluation

I wanted to get the value of an attribute from a pointer, inside another object, but accessing it without evaluating the reference got me the error

```
When attempting to read the slot's value (slot-value), the slot
POS is missing from the object *NODE-1*.
```

Here is a piece of code to simulate the error:

```
(defclass node ()
  ((pos 
    :initarg :pos
    :initform '(0 0)
    :accessor pos)))

(defclass edge ()
  ((vertices
    :initarg :vertices
    :accessor vertices)))

(defparameter *node-1* (make-instance 'node))
(defparameter *node-2* (make-instance 'node :pos '(100 100)))
(defparameter *edge-1* (make-instance 'edge :vertices '(*node-1* *node-2*)))
```

After that, evaluating this expression throws an error

```
(slot-value (car (slot-value *edge-1* 'vertices)) 'pos)
```

But this one has the desired behavior

```
(slot-value (eval (car (slot-value *edge-1* 'vertices))) 'pos)
```

I already know that `eval` is used for ugly hacks, that's why I'm trying to find a clever way to do what I need.

Comment: [funcall, reduce, apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571549)

Comment: check out (list foo) vs. '(foo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When attempting to read the slot's value (slot-value), the slot
>   `POS` is missing from the object `*NODE-1*`

`*node-1*` is not a CLOS instance. It's a symbol. `slot-value` needs a CLOS instance. Thus trying to compute the slot-value of a symbol makes no sense.

**Side note: `objects` in Common Lisp**

In the error message, the term *object* `*NODE-1*` means a specific symbol object at runtime. Symbols are objects, too. They are not CLOS objects, that is they are not CLOS instances of a CLOS class. But generally, even a symbol or a string are in Common Lisp considered to be *objects*.

**Why is it a symbol?**

You set the `vertices` slot to be the value of `'(*node-1* *node-2*)`. That's a literal list of two symbols, since you have quoted the list.

```
CL-USER 152 > '(*node-1* *node-2*)
(*NODE-1* *NODE-2*)

CL-USER 153 > (mapcar #'type-of *)
(SYMBOL SYMBOL)
```

**One uses objects directly**

If you want to compute a list of actual values of those symbols as variables, you need to compute a list of computed values:

```
CL-USER 154 > '((+ 1 2))
((+ 1 2))

CL-USER 155 > (list (+ 1 2))
(3)

CL-USER 160 > (list *node-1* *node-2*)
(#<NODE 402032A2C3> #<NODE 402032B98B>)

CL-USER 161 > (mapcar #'type-of *)
(NODE NODE)
```

The function `list` creates a fresh list with its arguments as contents.

**Getting the value of a symbol: use `SYMBOL-VALUE`**

```
(symbol-value '*node-1*)
```