# Elisp use apply on progn for list of functions

Tags: emacs, apply, elisp, elisp-macro

I am a new emacs user. And trying to write some Elisp to learn this software better. While I meet some problems.

I want to use `apply` on `progn` to run a list of functions in sequence. But I got errors as below. I am just confused and need some help to tell me how to achieve this in Elisp, thanks.

```lisp
(progn
  (+ 1 1)
  (+ 2 2)
  )
;; => 4

(apply #'progn ((+ 1 1) (+ 2 2)))
;; => Invalid function: (+ 1 1)

(apply #'progn ('(+ 1 1) '(+ 2 2)))
;; => Invalid function: '(+ 1 1)

(apply #'progn '((+ 1 1) (+ 2 2)))
;; => Invalid function: #<subr progn>
```

I toy play as above cause I come to emacs from vim. So I installed evil and evil number. And want back the vim number inc and dec bindings C-a, C-x. So I write a macro as blow to avoid boilerplate.

```lisp
(defmacro set-evil-number-keymap (key-set func &rest modes)
  `(apply 'progn
         ,(-map
          (lambda (mode)
            `(define-key ,(intern (concat "evil-" mode "-state-map")) (kbd ,key-set)
              ',(intern
                 (concat "evil-numbers/" func))))
          ,modes)))

(set-evil-number-keymap "C-a" "inc-at-pt" "normal" "insert")
(set-evil-number-keymap "C-x" "dec-at-pt" "normal" "insert")
```

My expectation is something below. While it just not run.

```lisp
(progn 
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-a") ’evil-numbers/inc-at-pt) (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-a") ’evil-numbers/inc-at-pt))

(progn 
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-x") ’evil-numbers/dec-at-pt) (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-x") ’evil-numbers/dec-at-pt))
```

Comment: What's the question now? Why `(apply 'progn ...)` doesn't work?

Comment: @xuchunyang cause `progn` is "special form", I thought it's a function but it is not. when do `macroexpand` on the `(apply 'progn ...)` I will get `(apply 'progn 
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-a") ’evil-numbers/inc-at-pt) (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-a") ’evil-numbers/inc-at-pt))`

Comment: Still not sure what's your question. You need one since this's a QA site, not a forum. Since you're using macro (actually you don't have to, the easy-to-read/write plain defun can work fine), you don't need `apply`. The purpose of `apply` is that, for example, you have some numbers stored in `some-numbers` and want the sum, you use `(apply '+ some-numbers)`, but with macro, you can just write `(cons '+ some-numbers)`, no apply is needed, you can think that macro should return a list, that is, a funcall such as `(+ 1 2 3)`, later then it will be evaluated automatically.

Comment: @xuchunyang Sorry for confusing you, the question can be clarified as to why can't `apply` on `progn`? I think `progn` is just a function. All "special form" should be just a function and can easily composite with others. Why elisp need the concept of "special form", make it distinguish from normal function, and prevent `apply` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `apply` in the macro, elisp have `,@` to flatten a list to args. So the correct answer is

```lisp
(defmacro set-evil-number-keymap (key-set func &rest modes)
  `(progn
          ,@(-map
             (lambda (mode)
               `(define-key ,(intern (concat "evil-" mode "-state-map")) (kbd ,key-set)
                  ',(intern
                     (concat "evil-numbers/" func))))
             ,modes)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `apply` on "special forms" like `progn` (see info (elisp)Special Forms), which have unique evaluation rules.

`progn` itself already provides a mechanism for sequenced evaluation, so your initial attempt does do what you want.  At the top-level, however, the forms will be executed sequentially anyway, so there is no need for a `progn` there.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought everything related to symbol, value, function, and macro. Now, I need to dig more about "special forms".

Comment: @Xiongchenyu I think that does about cover it -- except lisp symbols are represented as structs that can have both a value and function components -- see eg. `(symbol-function 'progn)`, `(symbol-value 'default-directory)`, so you could have `(defun f ())` and `(defvar f "f")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're expecting. `progn` returns value of the last forms, so 4 is excepted, consult `C-h f progn`:

> progn is a special form in `C source code'.
>
> (progn BODY...)
>
> Eval BODY forms sequentially and return value of last one.

If you want to see the result of `(+ 1 1)`, you need to ask for it, for example,

```
(list (+ 1 1) (+ 2 2))
;; => (2 4)

;; Step 1
(list 2 (+ 2 2))

;; Step 2
(list 2 4)

;; Step 3
(2 4)
```

The function arguments are evaluated from left to right. By the way, Emacs Lisp doesn't support multiple return value.

---

```
(apply #'progn ((+ 1 1) (+ 2 2)))
;; => Invalid function: (+ 1 1)
```

Since the second argument of the function `apply` is `((+ 1 1) (+ 2 2))`, Emacs needs to calculate its value and to calculate form like `(foo 1 2 3)`, `foo` has to be a function, but `(+ 1 2)` is not a function, it's just an ordinary list with 3 elements.

```
(apply #'progn ('(+ 1 1) '(+ 2 2)))
;; => Invalid function: '(+ 1 1)
```

`'(+ 1 2)`, that is, `(quote (+ 1 2))` isn't a function either, it's a list with two elements.

```
(apply #'progn '((+ 1 1) (+ 2 2)))
;; => Invalid function: #<subr progn>
```

`progn` isn't a function, it's a special form. `and`, `or`, `let` and `while` are all special forms, they are like macros, they doesn't evaluate arguments eagerly.
[(elisp) Calling Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) mentions

> special forms and macros do not make sense in `apply'.

Comment: I think my problem was not clear, so I just update it.

Comment: Besides use ,@ in a macro to flatten the list as args to feed `progn`. I just want to find some other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You had a bit of an XY problem, but what works for your nominal question is to

```
(eval (cons 'progn
            '((print (+ 1 1))
              (print (+ 2 2)))))
```

`eval` is [generally considered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571549/3588161) a beginner programmer's misunderstanding, but in this case you just can't use `apply` for the reasons Rorschach explained. Elisp actually follows the Common Lisp spec here, which [says](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node81.html) for `apply` that

> it is illegal for the symbol to be the name of a macro or special form

So, in general, you have to use `eval` directly on the program you've assembled by `cons`-ing a `progn` to your "instruction list".