# How to add quoted parameters to a quoted command in a shell script?

Tags: shell, quoting

I want to compose a command in a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

APPLICATION="date"
PARAMETER="-d '2020-01-01 1:23'"

CMD="${APPLICATION} ${PARAMETER}"

${CMD}
```

The 'PARAMETER' is supposed to hold parameters that need to be quoted themself. Unfortunately it does not work like this. Escaping them via `PARAMETER="-d \"2020-01-01 1:23\""` also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After you've build `CMD` up, it is just string. It contains what can be interpreted by you as a command, but the shell sees it as a bare string.

If you want the string to reinterpret it, you need to `eval` it:

```
eval "$CMD"
```

However, [`eval` is often considered *evil*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil).